# text pushing down background image of containing div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a bootstrap website that uses trianglify to generate background images for my hero div. I want text to go in the hero image, but it keeps pushing my image down.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="heroImageContainer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered">
                <p>Centered Text</p>
                <p>more text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Joshua</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
/*Universals*/
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*************/
#heroImageContainer{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/0.2.0/trianglify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var something = document.getElementById('heroImageContainer');
    var dimensions = something.getClientRects()[0];
    var pattern = Trianglify({
        width: dimensions.width,
        height: dimensions.height
    });
    heroImageContainer.appendChild(pattern.canvas());
</script>
```

Here is a working Fiddle of the problem

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11532/)

Comment: sorry not sure what you are trying to do. If you want as a background why is there a row within the hero div

Comment: Because i want to have content in the hero image. I dont understand your confusion

Answer (score 0):

How about position the canvas and then add a z-index on to the content so it places the text infront

```
canvas{
position:absolute
}
.col-centered{
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Your answer got me on the right track. I gave the containing div of the text a position of absolute. Fixed my issues